# How to add new dictionaries to a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries, through a loop, IF a condition is met?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I want to add new dictionaries (X) to a dictionary (D) of dictionaries (A_n) of dictionaries (B_m), IF a condition is met. And this has to be done through a loop (as X could be a 100,000 samples or more).

The condition for adding is: X[“POS”] == B“POS”]. All Dictionaries X have the same key names as all dictionaries B already in D.

So first, I want to check in A1 if the values of the X[“POS”] key are identical to Bn[“POS”] key. If True, I want to add Dictionary X to B, with name B_m+1 (or some other name).

If False, I want to check the same thing in A2, etc. If X[“POS”] is in none of them, I want to add a new dictionary A3 to D, of which X will then be the first dictionary and named D1.

The code I have so far for two levels is this which is falling far short of what is required, and gives an error: TypeError: string indices must be integers.

My problem is not just about adding something to a dictionary that is a few layers deep, but also in doing this using a loop.

Any suggestion what would be the simplest and most elegant way to do this?

[image: This is the structure I am trying to build.]

Edit:
**Example**

The dictionary D could look like this:

```
D = {'A1': [{'B1': {'value': [2, 3, 1, 0], 'POS_Seq': [2, 3, 1, 0]}}], 
'B2': {'value': [2, 3, 1, 0], 'POS_Seq': [2, 3, 1, 0]}}
```

The dictionary X to be added could be this:

```
X = {'value': [2,3,1,0], 'POS_Seq': [2,3,1,0]}
```

I would write the condition as something like this:

```
d['A1']['B1]['POS_Seq'] == X['POS_Seq']
```

This gives an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

After this, I would do something like:

```
d['A1']['B3] = X
```

I know what I am trying to is complicated, but I wonder whether I should use dictionaries for this. Maybe lists within a DataFrame would be easier. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a *[mcve]*?

Comment: I will try and post.